# function monotonic and $f(X)$ dense in some interval

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, monotonic and $f(X)$ dense in some  limited interval, prove that exists a unique function ( monotonic) $\varphi:\bar{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ( $\bar{X}$ is the clausure of X), such that $\varphi\mid_X=f$  and $\varphi$ is continuous.
I started to see some previous results that can help,

- If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ monotonic and $f(X)$ dense in some interval then $f$ is continuous.
- If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ monotonic and $f(X)$ is an interval then $f$ is continuous

Comment: What do $X$ and $\bar{X}$ denote?

Comment: is already edited, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose without loss of generality that $f$ is increasing.

For all $x \in \bar{X}$, take $\{ x_n \}_n \subset X$ a sequence such that $x_n \to x$. It is easy to show that there exists a monotone subsequence of $\{ x_n \}_n$, call it $\{ x_{n_k} \}_k$.

Then define
$$\varphi(x) = \left\{
\begin{matrix}
\sup_k f(x_{n_k}) & \mbox{ if $\{ x_{n_k} \}_k$ is increasing} \\
\inf_k f(x_{n_k}) & \mbox{ if $\{ x_{n_k} \}_k$ is decreasing}
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$

Showing that this function is well defined is a quite tedious work. This involves the fact that $f$ is monotonic, and so limits on the right are simply $\inf$s and limits on the left are simply $\sup$s.

Then, $\varphi$ clearly extends $f$ (if $x \in X$ you can take $x_n = x$ constant), is monotonic (check it!) and $f(X) \subset \phi(\bar{X}) \subset \overline{f(X)}$, so it is dense in a bounded interval.

This means that $\varphi$ is continuous.