# Continuous Monotone Extention of a Monotone Function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

first post here!
I need to show that, given a function $f:(X\subset\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(X)$ is dense in a bounded interval, there is a unique continuous monotonic extension. Lets call this $\varphi:\overline X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $\varphi|_X =f \quad \text{and} \quad \overline X \ \text{is the clousure} $

I've seen this answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156256/function-monotonic-and-fx-dense-in-some-interval) but couldn't understand it very well or guarantee the uniqueness of  $\varphi$

Comment: What is $X?\,\,$

Comment: The domain of our function. Is holds no restriction

Comment: do you mean that $f$ is monotone continuous on a subset of the real numbers?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I will edit

Answer (score 1):

The question you liked shows it exists. To see uniqueness:

Let $x \in \bar{X}$. Then take any sequence in $X$ converging to $x$ (at least one such sequence exists by the definition of $\bar{X}$).

Then, since $\phi$ is continuous and extends $f$,

$$
\phi(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}{ \phi(x_n) } = \lim_{n \to \infty}{ f(x_n) }.
$$

The above does not depend on the choice of the sequence. So any $\phi$ continuos extending $f$ will satisfy the above condition which uniquely determines the value of $\phi(x)$ for any $x \in \bar{X}$.